# Conditional Anchors

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a website in which I need to have conditional navigation. As such:

Clicked item in Menu

1: if frontpage, go to #id

```
(example <a href="#events">)
```

2: if subpage, go to front- or other subpage

```
(example <a href="../events/>)
```

The website is a .net website and the navigation is located on the masterpage.

I have thought of different ways to solve this, either with **.Net & C#, JS or JQuery.**
In .Net I thought I could assign asp controls and simply serve different links in different subpages and then have some sort of loop or replacement with the codebehind.

If anyone has any idea how to figure out this, please write. Thanks in advance!

Code examples:

```
<li>
<a href="<%--../coaching/--%>#Coaching" title="title text">Coaching & Consulting</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont dont you create a user control with your menu?

You can check it out here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fb3w5b53(v=vs.100).aspx
and pass some parameter to the user control and handle the link changing in there.

You can have that menu stored somewhere else, like in a xml file somewhere and render it to the desired html.

Answer (score 1):

I followed Vfleitao's advice and tried User Controls. Just so others can see how I solved it here are some code examples:

**The header user control:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="header.ascx.cs" Inherits="menu" %>
<ul class="show-for-large-up">
        <li><a href="<%= this.AboutUsLink %>" title="">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="<%= this.CoachingLink %>" title="">Coaching</a></li>
        <li><a href="<%= this.ConsultingLink %>" title="">Consulting</a></li>
        <li><a href="<%= this.EventsLink %>"  title="">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="<%= this.ContactLink %>"  title="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Codebehind:**

```
private string aboutUsLink;
private string coachingLink;
private string consultingLink;
private string eventsLink;
private string contactLink;

public string AboutUsLink
{
    get { return aboutUsLink; }
    set { aboutUsLink = value; }
}

public string CoachingLink
{
    get { return coachingLink; }
    set { coachingLink = value; }
}

public string ConsultingLink
{
    get { return consultingLink; }
    set { consultingLink = value; }
}

public string EventsLink
{
    get { return eventsLink; }
    set { eventsLink = value; }
}

public string ContactLink
{
    get { return contactLink; }
    set { contactLink = value; }
}
```

**Use in page:**

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="My" TagName="header" Src="~/header.ascx" %> <%-- Maybe this could be moved to the master page? --%>
<My:header runat="server" ID="MyHeader" AboutUsLink="#OmOs" CoachingLink="#Coaching" ConsultingLink="#Consulting" EventsLink="#Events" ContactLink="#Contact" />
```

**Or**

```
<My:header runat="server" ID="MyHeader" AboutUsLink="../about/" CoachingLink="../coaching/" ConsultingLink="../consulting/" EventsLink="../events/" ContactLink="../contact/" />
```

*Sources for help:*
http://asp.net-tutorials.com/user-controls/creating/